# Swapping terms using Assignment de-structuring wont work inside a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let a = 'alpha', b = 'beta';
[a,b] = [b,a];
```

This swaps the values of a and b as intended;
but when placed inside a function it doesn't work

```
let c = 'charlie', d = 'delta';
swapVar = (x,y) => [x,y] = [y,x]
swapVar(c,d);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't think those are the same variables.  They are scoped only to the arrow function and then die.  How are you testing that they have actually been swapped?

Comment: Parameters are passed by value in Javascript, not by reference. Assigning to the variables inside the function has no effect on the caller's variables.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
let a = 'alpha', b = 'beta';
[a,b] = [b,a];
```

You're swapping the values of `a` and `b`.

When you do

```
let c = 'charlie', d = 'delta';
swapVar = (x,y) => {
   // x and y are separate variables scoped within this block
   [x,y] = [y,x]
   console.log(x,y); // it is swapped alright but isn't reflected on c and d
   c = x;
   d = y; 
   // Now the value will have been reflected.
}
swapVar(c,d);
```

So, within the function the values are swapped but aren't reflected outside. You could modify the program like this:

```
swapVar = (x,y) => [y,x]
[c, d] = swapVar(c, d); // now you're reflecting the swapped values on the outside
```

To have the intended effect.

Comment: `swapVar` in your final example becomes completely useless. Better to just `[c, d] = [d, c];`, the extra level of indirection has no benefit, not even readability, and actually makes the return value of the function misleading (as it simply returns an array with the values reversed, which is not "swapping".

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I added that to prove that assignment destructuring can indeed be done within the function but you've to use the return value. The title seemed specific to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the swap in a scope where the variables aren't being "exported".

In the first example, you act on the actual variables `a` and `b` in the scope they are defined in.

However, in the second example, you are acting on the variables `x` and `y` which are the same value as `c` and `d` but aren't the actual `c` and `d` since they are primitives so the `c` and `d` outside the scope of the arrow function is not affected.

```js
{
  let a = 'alpha',
    b = 'beta';
  console.log("Test 1");
  console.log(`before a: ${a} b: ${b}`);
  [a, b] = [b, a];
  console.log(`after a: ${a} b: ${b}`);
}


{
  let c = 'charlie',
    d = 'delta';
  console.log("Test 2");
  console.log(`before c: ${c} d: ${d}`);
  swapVar = (x, y) => [x, y] = [y, x]

  /*
  function swapVarExpanded(x, y) {
    const tmp = [y, x];
    x = tmp[0];
    y = tmp[1];
    // Doesn't actually matter 
    // because x and y die at the next closing curly brace due to scope
  }
  */

  swapVar(c, d);
  console.log(`after c: ${c} d: ${d}`);
}
```